# Error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: xml, runtime-error, placeholder, genshi

I want to generate a printout

and one of the fields that i want to display is the sum of the duration on the printout, I have called the duration of each line then i have applied the sum directly to those lines and Here is the code:

PS: I have a **timesheet** model and the **lines** as a one2many field table-relation

```
  <text:p text:style-name="P31"><text:placeholder text:placeholder-type="text">&lt;format_duration(sum(line.duration for line in timesheet.lines))&gt;</text:placeholder></text:p>
```

But there was an error tell me:

```
  File "<string>", line 480, in <Expression '__relatorio_guess_type(__relatorio_store_cache(140239131800968, format_duration(sum(line.duration for line in timesheet.lines))))'>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: The code expects something iterable, but it receives a datetime.timedelta. Either you change the code or provide it a different value, but only you have the info required to make that decision. BTW: It would help to have an executable [mcve], not just this partial info. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Lastly, it's always a good idea to add a language tag.

Comment: The [python] tag was added, but there is no Python code in the question.

Comment: Now the [python] tag is removed, but there is still no [mcve].